# SendingSimpleGoals

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, Following the SendingSimpleGoals tutorial

> http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

, after running the executable, Waiting for the move_base action server to come up waits forever. Can anyone suggest me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196674/sendingsimplegoals/) by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must have another node running the server.
If you have in your robot `/move_base` already implemented then it is automatically started.
Otherwise you must provide the server with your own code.

The code in the tutorial is just half of the whole story :)

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on 2014-11-04**:
Can you tell me what is the all story? Where can I learn what should I do in detail?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-11-04**:
The story is very simple (conceptually). You need a server running in the backgorund or your client (the program you have run) never will extablish a connection to the server. There are some package like /move_base which start "automatically" a server. In that case, starting that node,...

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-11-04**:
...you can get your connection.
I can tell you one thing: try to integrate your knowledge with books (ROS by Example 1 & 2 is the best one to me). "in detail" is a good word...I m still learning ROS